# Divide string into substrings in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, substring

I have a string `1122333344555566778888`
I need to substring it and as a result get `[11, 22, 3333, 44, 5555, 66, 77, 8888]`
Is it possible to do it in a beautiful way or I need to hardcode it and eight time use `string.substring(beginning, ending)` function and then put into `array`?

**Edit:** String can contain not only repeated numbers. `AB CG HERD KJ 98HQ 0K 1E OOQW` it also example!

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is possible to do the splitting by arbitratry numbers.

Comment: Are the groups always numbers and in order?

Comment: What is the logic behind the splitting? Do you want to separate different numbers, or what is the goal?

Comment: I tried to hardcode it and eight time use string.substring(beginning, ending) function, but the code looks like terrible. As a result, I am looking for a beautiful solution.

Comment: @Bob I think my solution produces the string array you want to see.

Comment: How about implementing a method like: `String[] split(String s, int... sizes)` that splits a string given the sizes of each part?

Comment: Do you want to split based on A) predetermined lengths of the parts, regardless of content, or B) contiguous same-character blocks regardless of length?

Comment: @Bob if your string will contain not only numbers, then my solution is the way to go, i think.

Answer (score 4):

use the pattern: `((\d)\2*)`

```
String input = "1122333344555566778888";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((\\d)\\2*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found " + m.group(1));
}
```

produces:

```
11
22
3333
44
5555
66
77
8888
```

edit: if its numbers as well as spaces and letters use the pattern `(([\d\w\s])\2*)`

Comment: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(([\d\w\s]\2*)"); gives an error in eclipse - invalid escape sequence

Comment: in java you need to escape the escape so you would need to use `(([\\d\\w\\s]\\2*)` to make it valid @Bob

Comment: Another error too: Unclosed group near index 14
(([\d\w\s]\2*)

Comment: sorry that was my mistake, i missed off a closing bracket ) updated answer to use `(([\d\w\s])\2*)` @Bob

Answer (score 3):

You can use the regular expression of **repeating characters**:

```
String input = "1122333344555566778888";
String regex = "(\\w)\\1+";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
String[] substrings = new String[input.length()];

int index = 0;

while (m.find())
    substrings[index++] = m.group();

for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    System.out.println(substrings[i]);
```

**Output:**

```
11
22
3333
44
5555
66
77
8888
```

**Important Note:**

`substrings` array contains null entries since its length is equal to the input string's length. If your string contains non-repeating sequential characters then this array might not have null entries. Watch on `substrings` for `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

there is no delimiter in this string to be able to use .split(), if you had a delimeter between what you want to have a substring such as 11-22-3333- ... etc, it will be easy to use

```
String[] splits = asseltClasses.split("-");
```

Comment: I do not have any delimiters here, just plain string

Answer (score 0):

Based on BlueBullet's ...

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.*;
public class MyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "1122333344555566778888";
        String regex = "(\\w)\\1+";

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);

        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (m.find()) l.add(m.group());

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(l.toArray()));
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
[11, 22, 3333, 44, 5555, 66, 77, 8888]
```

Answer (score 0):

This beautiful enough? It's just one line...

```
String parts = input.replaceAll("(.)(?!\\1)", "$1\0").split("\0");
```

---

Here's a test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "1122333344555566778888";
    String[] parts = input.replaceAll("(.)(?!\\1)", "$1\0").split("\0");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
}
```

Output:

```
[11, 22, 3333, 44, 5555, 66, 77, 8888]
```

---

Note that there is one very minor hitch with this solution - the character after `$1` in the call to `replaceAll()` must not be possible to have in the input. I chose the null character `'\0'` (ie hex zero) to be *fairly* safe.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:
Given a string that is not sorted, "ABCABCABC", you can sort it by converting it to a Char[] array, then using Arrays.sort(), turning it into AAABBBCCC.

```
    public String[] sortThis(String inputData) {
    String input = "ABCABCABC"; //make this whatever you want (or set to inputData)
    String[] temp = new String[input.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length();i++) //initialize the array, or it prints "null"
        temp[i] = "";
    int index = 0;
    char[] info = input.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(info);

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) { // fill the temp array
        temp[index] += info[i];
        if(i+1 < input.length())
            if(i < input.length() && info[i] != info[i+1])
                index++;
    }

    String[] answer = new String[index+1]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < index+1; i++) // shorten the array
        answer[i] = temp[i];

    return answer;
    }
```

**Output:**

```
    [AAA, BBB, CCC]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe u want to use this:**

```
var str="1122333344555566778888"; //whatever
b=0;outpt="";
while(b<=18){
if(b==4|b==10|b==18){e=4;p=4}else{e=2;p=2}
outpt+=str.substr(b,e)+", ";b+=p;}
alert(outpt);
```

**Output:**

```
11, 22, 3333, 44, 5555, 66, 77, 8888,
```